# Apache Karaf Cave Windows Issues

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am having issue with Apache Karaf Cave in windows, specifically, with the repository.xml generation that happens when running "cave:repository-update nice-repo".

In Windows, the repository.xml that is generated has bad paths in the uri...

```
<repository name="test-repo" lastmodified="20150512044028.680">
<resource id="org.apache.felix.ipojo/1.8.0" 
symbolicname="org.apache.felix.ipojo" 
presentationname="Apache Felix iPOJO"     
uri="file:/C:/foo/bar/apache-karaf-3.0.2/foo/bundle_repo/test-   repo/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.ipojo/1.8.0/org.apache.felix.ipojo- 1.8.0.jar" 
version="1.8.0">
```

As you can se the uri is using a full path, as opposed to a relative path.  Here is the Linux url for comparison.

```
uri="org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.ipojo/1.8.0/org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.8.0.jar"
```

I have reviewed the Cave documentation and config files in $KARAF_HOME/etc but have not been able to find anything that helps in resolving this issue.

Has anyone come across this before or perhaps have any suggestions?

Comment: most likely you hit a bug. Best to ask on the karaf users-mailinglist or directly create a jira issue for it.

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-3727 to track this. I gonna fix this issue. Regards
JB

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround as well. When creating the repository using the cave:repository-create command, you can specify the location using the -l option. When you do that, for windows, use forward slashes instead of back slashes. This will cause the repository.xml to show as you expect. Here is an example:

```
cave:repository-create -l /C:/foo/bar some-repo
```